# How to make an image clickable in jira comment, so it pops up as if you click on attached image in attachment area?

Tags: jira

I'm talking desktop browser experience, e.g. chrome. 
In jira, if I attach the image I can use it in my comment - and it's great!
I usually use `width=800px` so the whole image can be seen in the comment.

So I can write something like this:

> Here's the screenshot
>
> `!my-screenshot-image.jpg|width=600px!`

The problem is that sometimes **screenshot is too big** and when shrunk to smaller size, e.g. 600px, is **not readable**.
When you click on the image in *attached files area* then it pops up and this is what I want in the comment section.

I was wondering if there's any **parameter** that would make it happen?
Is there a list of parameters that can be used when "embedding" image somewhere? I only seem to find `width` parameter.

P.S. When you open jira ticket on **mobile** - it looks fine and image is actually clickable - when you click on it it opens up a page with just image in it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want this to allow a small image in the comment to be expanded into a larger light box view:

```
!my-screenshot-image.jpg|thumbnail!
```

Per the source for JIRA 6.3, the following are also valid attributes for images:

```
align
border
bordercolor
alt
title
longdesc
height
width
src
lang
dir
hspace
vspace
ismap
usemap
id
class
```

Comment: thumbnail is a great option to know and thanks for hinting this - I'm sure will be using this. 
But unfortunately it doesn't work with width=XXXpx.
So what I'm saying this wouldn't work: `!my-screenshot-image.jpg|thumbnail|width=600px!`

Comment: The correct syntax for that is `!my-screenshot-image.jpg|thumbnail, width=800px!`, although it probably doesn't do what you want (generate an 800px upsampled version of a low-res thumbnail :-( ).

Comment: Well, this is great to know anyway!

Comment: I just added a list of the other acceptable attributes for images, since your question mentioned wanting a reference for those too.

Comment: Thanks Scott, much appreciated. Is there link you could share e.g. Jira documentation or usage scenarios?

Comment: Except for thumbnail, I believe they are all [HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Comment: If you really care to dig in and if you are a JIRA licensee, you can download the JIRA sources from your my.atlassian.com account. Some relevant files are `jira-project/jira-components/jira-core/src/main/java/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/renderer/wiki/embedded/JiraEmbeddedImageRenderer.java`, and from within `dependencySources/atlassian-renderer-X.Y.Z-sources.jar`, `com/atlassian/renderer/embedded/EmbeddedImage.java`.

Answer (score -1):

This one works for me.

> !my-screenshot-image.jpg|thumbnail,
>   width=800px!

Comment: This appears to just copy the above answer. What does this answer provide that the other doesn't?