# Jira: How can I make images part of my ticket description?

Tags: email, jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I have set up an email account which receives emails and creates ticket in Jira against each email. Now if email includes any pictures as part of email body then I want to show them as part of corresponding ticket body in Jira. Currently they are becoming attachments even though 'description' field is a  'Wiki style renderer' field.
Please guide me what to do I will be truly thankful.

Comment: But other people have asked about Jira? Where can I ask about Jira?

Comment: AFAIK it was decided on meta a while ago that SO is the correct place for JIRA questions. I don't think the built in email handler can do what you want automatically, but see this question. The formatting can be applied within the description too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935678/how-to-make-an-image-clickable-in-jira-comment-so-it-pops-up-as-if-you-click-on/

Comment: There's also a Web applications SE site, which I can't easily link to right now since I'm on mobile, but I think that might be the most appropriate place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Scott Dudley already commented, JIRA's built-in mail handler does not support inline images in created issues.

However, there are a few commercial add-ons that do support this. Some popular ones are [Enterprise Mail Handler for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.javahollic.jira.jemh-ui/server/overview) and [Email This Issue](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.metainf.jira.plugin.emailissue/server/overview#).

For the relevant documentation, check:

- [JEMH Overview](https://thepluginpeople.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JEMH)
- [HTML Content Preserved with Inline Images](https://www.meta-inf.hu/display/PLUG/Mail+Handler+and+Auto-reply+emails)